# CFMAIL not working

Tags: coldfusion

I'm testing out a contact form and I can't figure out why I'm not receiving any of the emails. I have checked my spam folder and my applications developer assures me that the email server is working correctly. I have tested all the variables with CFOUTPUT.

```
<cfmail
    from="#form.email#" 
    to="myemail@gmail.com"
    subject="Request a Quote"
    type="html">
    Name: #form.name#<br/>
    Email: #form.email# <br/>
    Phone: #form.phone#<br />
    City: #form.city#<br />
    State: #form.state#<br />
    Wheel: #form.wheel#<br />
    <cfif isdefined("form.size")>
        Size: #form.size#<br />
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("form.vehicle_info")>
    Vehicle: #form.vehicle_info#<br />
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("form.finishes")>
        Finishes: #form.finishes#<br />
    </cfif>
</cfmail>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I am not receiving any of the emails

Comment: Have you checked the mailsent log?  How about the undeliverable folder?

Comment: Have you checked your log files? Have you switched mail logging on and checked what *that* is logging?

Comment: I'm looking into it. I don't have direct access to the server admin

Comment: Also check your http files.  Maybe nobody is requesting that page.

Comment: Your _code_ looks fine, so there's something else going on. Unfortunately, all we could do is guess what the actual problem is. Check that sent mail is being logged and check the `mail.log` and `mailsent.log` files. If there's nothing there then you need to investigate at the mail server. As it stands your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Actually, "the code is fine" is the answer I was looking for. Now I can look into server/mail server issues

Answer (score 0):

put tag  before <cfmail and end of "</cfmail tag" Then for value from must be in format email address even it is not exist. example from="abcd@abc.com"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say?  Could you edit to clarify... also, adding explanation helps make it a better answer